# Migrating from TerstRPC to live testnet (Ropsten)

Tags: blockchain, testnets, ropsten

I have successfully developed my smart contracts in Solidity and the scripts using the web3 API to deploy them on the testRPC. Now, I would like to test on a testnet network: Ropsten.

**How can I migrate from testRPC to Ropsten?**

I know that I need to create a node and download the entire blockchain. In order to do this, I used:

```
geth --testnet removedb
geth --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

Once this step is done, I need to create an account and mine a bit to get some Ethers. Then, I can connect to this node and deploy my smart contracts with my JS scripts.

Can someone confirm that I am on the right track?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your information revivaled Ropsten testnet is having some issues at the moment. I suggest joining to the Gitter chat for the latest information. https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten/

Comment: Is it maybe why I get this error constantly? `I0411 15:58:59.047063 eth/downloader/downloader.go:711] Peer fd008499e9c4662f [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #396912 [00000000…] <= #396912 limit` @MikkoOhtamaa

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to deploy a smart contract, you can also use third parties like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts). I personally find it much comfortable.

You can compile the contract code using [remix-online solidity compiler](http://remix.ethereum.org) and get the bytecode from there.
You can connect your MEW to Ropsten or any test network of you choice and deploy the contract using MEW.

You can also access the contract on MEW using it's address and abi.

But if you want to use geth, then you are on right track. You need to download the complete chain, you can use `--fast --cache=1024` options for fast syncing. And next, create an account and fund it with test ethers. Then you can either use Ethereum wallet or geth console to deploy and interact with your smart contract.

Have a look at [Is there a quicker way than geth --fast to download the Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/is-there-a-quicker-way-than-geth-fast-to-download-the-ethereum-blockchain) and [How can I get a geth node to download the blockchain quickly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-get-a-geth-node-to-download-the-blockchain-quickly/4210)

Answer (score 0):

The process seems correct, although it may slightly vary depending on what frameworks you use. You can also skip actual mining by using a free [testnet faucet](https://blog.b9lab.com/when-we-first-built-our-faucet-we-deployed-it-on-the-morden-testnet-70bfbf4e317e) that can be used to recieve just enough ETH for testing.

Comment: I don't use any frameworks such as Truffle or Embark. I just have my scripts in javascript, and my smart contracts in solidity. Then, I'm planning to use `geth js` to load my js files that will technically deploy my smart contracts.